# How can I implement Material Components on iOS?

Tags: ios, material-components

What's a good way to implement [Material Components](http://Material.io) in my iOS app without writing it all myself?

Comment: You can use [Material-Controls-For-iOS](https://github.com/fpt-software/Material-Controls-For-iOS) or [Material](https://github.com/CosmicMind/Material) frameworks. They both have needed UI elements, icons and animations with Material design.

Answer (score 3):

Artem Novichkov is correct:

Use Google's repository of open-source [Material Design Components for iOS](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-ios) on github.

Comment: We even have a [public discord server](https://discord.gg/uD4hJnY) if you have any implementation questions